# How to unsubscribe from onTouch() event

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

When application is started I run a custom pop-up till a user touches the screen. When screen is touched I catch it with event onTouch() and cancel the pop-up. From this point I don't need the event anymore. 
The problem is the event is alive and continues to jump up every time a user touches the screen. 
Is there any way to unsubscribe from this event? Something like in c# -= eventName.
The code is below:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (!_stopToast)
    {
    _hintToast.cancel();
    _stopToast = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: overwrite the listener with yourView.setOnTouchListener(null);

Comment: Wow, this is works! Thank you very much for such a quick and excellent solution))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such method (lets say *removeTouchListener* or similar) which will help you to remove an already defined touch listener from a view. Setting `null` to **setOnTouchListener** won't help too. What you can do is to create a new object reference of `OnTouchListener` class which does nothing and set it in **setOnTouchListener**. For example:

```
public final OnTouchListener dummyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent rawEvent) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

And simply use it as below:

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(dummyOnTouchListener);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's great! Although the null works in my case as I tried. I'll try this one.

Comment: To explain:  Setting `setOnTouchListener` to `null` won't work in many cases, if you've implemented `onTouch` method in the view, because the result is to "fall back" to the view's `onTouch` method - which in this question the goal is to eliminate.  If instead of implementing `onTouch`, the original implementation had attached a listener, using code similar to what is in this answer (but instead of `return false;`, the method body would do what you wanted with the touch), then it would be easily removed by `yourView.setOnTouchListener(null);`  Wouldn't it?